# How to determine which UNIQUE index enforces the PRIMARY KEY in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Given a table with two unique indexes, as shown below, how does one determine which unique index corresponds to the PRIMARY KEY, as opposed to other UNIQUE indexes on that table?

The user_indexes and user_ind_columns do not seem to carry that information. Thanks, --DD

PS: Short of explicitly naming the indexes and using a naming convention of course.

```
SQL> create table tt (id number not null primary key, name varchar2(64 char) not null unique, info varchar2(4000));

SQL> create index tt_idx on tt(info);

SQL> select INDEX_NAME, INDEX_TYPE, UNIQUENESS from user_indexes where TABLE_NAME='TT';

INDEX_NAME           INDEX_TYPE                  UNIQUENES
-------------------- --------------------------- ---------
SYS_C0029541         NORMAL                      UNIQUE
SYS_C0029542         NORMAL                      UNIQUE
TT_IDX               NORMAL                      NONUNIQUE

SQL> select * from user_ind_columns where TABLE_NAME='TT';

INDEX_NAME           TABLE_NAME           COLUMN_NAME  COLUMN_POSITION COLUMN_LENGTH CHAR_LENGTH DESC
-------------------- -------------------- ------------ --------------- ------------- ----------- ----
SYS_C0029541         TT                   ID                         1            22           0 ASC
SYS_C0029542         TT                   NAME                       1           256          64 ASC
TT_IDX               TT                   INFO                       1          4000        4000 ASC
```

**Update:**

Here's the result of running Florin's query, which clearly shows which index enforces the **P** RIMARY KEY:

```
SQL> select constraint_name, constraint_type, index_name from user_constraints where table_name='TT';

CONSTRAINT_NAME                C INDEX_NAME
------------------------------ - --------------------
SYS_C0029539                   C
SYS_C0029540                   C
SYS_C0029541                   P SYS_C0029541
SYS_C0029542                   U SYS_C0029542
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select 
   owner, constraint_name, table_name, index_name 
from 
   user_constraints 
where constraint_type in ('P');
```

Answer (score 5):

Primary keys can be supported by a non-unique index, so it's not really the index that enforces uniqueness at all, it's the constraint itself.

If you create a primary key or unique key against a set of columns then by default a unique index is created, except that if the constraint is declared to be deferrable then a non-unique index is created. A primary key or unique key can also be declared against a set of columns that are covered by a non-unique index without a new unique index being created.

So, it is not the uniqueness of a supporting index that enforces a primary key constraint, any more than it is the presence of a NOT NULL column constraint that enforces that a primary key column must be non-null -- in both cases it is the primary key constraint itself that is responsible.

You should definitely name all of your constraints though, apart from column NOT NULL declarations.

Comment: I'm sorry, but unless I'm mistaken, primary keys are supposed to enforce the identity of a row, which therefore implies uniqueness (and not-nullness too it seems). So can you precise what you mean by your first sentence?

Comment: Yes they do, but they do so themselves not through the presence of a unique index.

Comment: I've reread your answer more carefully, and this time I got it. Thanks for this precision. This is enlightening to me.

Answer (score 1):

In rare cases indexes columns can be a superset of PK's columns. For example index on (A, B, C) while PK is only (A, B).

Answer (score 0):

As your query shows, you have only one index on the primary key column, there is no confusion possible here !

The unique index on column `ID` (`SYS_C0029541`) is used to enforce the primary key.

In the general case you can use the `INDEX_NAME` column of the [`USER_CONSTRAINTS`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_1046.htm#REFRN20047) view to find the index used to police a unique constraint or a primary key:

```
SELECT constraint_name, index_name, constraint_type
  FROM user_constraints
 WHERE table_name = 'TT';
```

Comment: the point of my question was to infer the index of the PRIMARY KEY, if any, not knowing a-priori which is/are the PK column(s). So your first sentence makes no sense to me :). But your query did answer my question though, thanks.